# Find the inverse map $f^{−1}$

Tags: linear-algebra

$f : ℝ → ℝ$ given by

$f(x, y) = (x + y − 3, x + 4)$

I'm not sure how to find the inverse map, any help/advice would be very much appreciated.

Comment: $f$ is a map on ${\mathbb R}^2$, not ${\mathbb R}$.

Answer (score 3):

$f(x,y) = (u, v)$

$v = x+4\\
x = v-4$

$u = x+y-3\\
u = v-4 + y -3\\
y =u-v + 7$

$f^{-1}(u,v) = (v-4, u-v+7)$